# Citadel Server with Spamassassin + MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, mail-server, spamassassin

I've been using Citadel with Spamassassin without any problems. I used to setup spam filters by adding rules to the local.cf files but now I want to integrate spamassassin with a database to store per user rules.

So I followed this guide (https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/UsingSQL) and managed to configure spamassassin with MySQL. It works when I set global rules ($GLOBAL) on the database but it doesn't when I set rules for a specific user.

After some digging on the internet and analyzing LOG files I noticed that Spamassassin is using default user 'nobody' to query on the database, which means that Citadel is not providing the username.

According to Citadel's documentation, it implements Spamassassin's protocol on its own rather than using SPAMC.

Is there a way to configure citadel to provide username info to Spamassassin?

Thank you.